# Can wavelets be used for texture discrimination?

Tags: signal-processing, integral-transforms, wavelets

I've recently been studying wavelet analysis with a view to differentiating certain areas of texture images where the texture differs from the background pattern (which is quite random); for example a small ink smudge on a photo of sand.

I've seen a lot of applications of Gabor wavelets used to pick out textural differences in things like fabrics, and other regular type patterns but I've not been able to find any applications of things like Daubechie/Harr wavelets for anything other than image compression.

Can different wavelet families be used to pick out textural differences such as my example?